# Ansible - when statement task always return false value

Tags: ansible

I've got 1 master node from which I would like to instal NewRelic agents remotely depedning on the OS I have on them. Some of them are Amazon 2 Amis and some Amazon 1 Ami.
I put when statement in the Ansible Playbook's task in the following way:

```
- name: Enable repo for Amazon Linux 2/Red Hat 7v
  yum_repository:
    name: newrelic-infra
    description: NewRelic repo
    baseurl: https://download.newrelic.com/infrastructure_agent/linux/yum/el/7/$basearch
  when: (ansible_distribution == "Amazon" and ansible_distribution_version == "(Karoo)") or
        (ansible_distribution == "RedHat" and ansible_distribution_major_version == "7")

- name: Enable repo for Amazon Linux 1/Red Hat 6v
  yum_repository:
    name: newrelic-infra
    description: NewRelic repo
    baseurl: https://download.newrelic.com/infrastructure_agent/linux/yum/el/6/$basearch
  when: (ansible_distribution == "Amazon" and ansible_distribution_version == "2018.03") or
        (ansible_distribution == "RedHat" and ansible_distribution_major_version == "6")
```

I understand that when statement should check the if statement and proceed further. Nevertheless, whenever I run playbook I receive that if statement is false and it's skipping above tasks. What might be the root cause?

I've already checked on remote host ansible_distribution and ansible_distribution_version if strings match. I suppose it must be some syntax problem as I'm new in ansible. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Post: `ansible_distribution, ansible_distribution_version, ansible_distribution_major_version` and also post the output. Generally make it [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (or include a crystal ball). [I downvoted because lacking an MCVE makes it hard to answer](https://idownvotedbecau.se/nomcve/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your statements look ok. If I create a test case from the sparse info you provided and what I can observe when gathering facts from my own hosts, I can detect old/recent distributions correctly using your conditions. See my example below.

I suggest you double check the data gathered from your host to understand why it doesn't match. The easiest way for that: from the same host your use to launch your playbook, run

```
ansible -i path/to/your_inventory.ini your_target_group_name -m setup -a "filter=ansible_distribution*"
```

Here is the `test.yml` playbook I wrote to test your (known-so-far) values and your conditions

```
---
- name: Statements for checking old/recent distribs
  hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false

  vars:
    os_list:
      - ansible_distribution: "Amazon"
        ansible_distribution_version: "(Karoo)"
        ansible_distribution_major_version: "(Karoo)"
      - ansible_distribution: "Amazon"
        ansible_distribution_version: "2018.03"
        ansible_distribution_major_version: "2018"
      - ansible_distribution: "RedHat"
        ansible_distribution_version: "6.x"
        ansible_distribution_major_version: "6"
      - ansible_distribution: "RedHat"
        ansible_distribution_version: "7.x"
        ansible_distribution_major_version: "7"

  tasks:

    - name: Check conditions for recent distribs
      debug:
        msg: "This is a recent distrib"
      loop: "{{ os_list }}"
      loop_control:
        label: "{{ item.ansible_distribution }}-{{ item.ansible_distribution_version }}"
      when: (
              item.ansible_distribution == "Amazon"
              and
              item.ansible_distribution_version == "(Karoo)"
            )
            or
            (
              item.ansible_distribution == "RedHat"
              and
              item.ansible_distribution_major_version == "7"
            )

    - name: Check conditions for old distribs
      debug:
        msg: "This is an old distrib"
      loop: "{{ os_list }}"
      loop_control:
        label: "{{ item.ansible_distribution }}-{{ item.ansible_distribution_version }}"
      when: (
              item.ansible_distribution == "Amazon"
              and
              item.ansible_distribution_version == "2018.03"
            )
            or
            (
              item.ansible_distribution == "RedHat"
              and
              item.ansible_distribution_major_version == "6"
            )
```

And the result

```
PLAY [Statements for checking old/recent distribs] ************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Check conditions for recent distribs] *******************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item=Amazon-(Karoo)) => {
    "msg": "This is a recent distrib"
}
skipping: [localhost] => (item=Amazon-2018.03) 
skipping: [localhost] => (item=RedHat-6.x) 
ok: [localhost] => (item=RedHat-7.x) => {
    "msg": "This is a recent distrib"
}

TASK [Check conditions for old distribs] **********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
skipping: [localhost] => (item=Amazon-(Karoo)) 
ok: [localhost] => (item=Amazon-2018.03) => {
    "msg": "This is an old distrib"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=RedHat-6.x) => {
    "msg": "This is an old distrib"
}
skipping: [localhost] => (item=RedHat-7.x) 

PLAY RECAP ****************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

As you can see it does the job as expected. So either your data is not gathered correctly or your check the wrong values.

**Note**: When @Vladimir Botka asks for an MCVE in the comments, this is a typical example.

Comment: Thank you for response and apologies I couldn't answer earlier. By checking ansible hosts with the command you proposed I got the following information:

"ansible_distribution_major_version": "2018" for the Amazon v1 AMI
and  "ansible_distribution_major_version": "2" for the Amazon 2 AMI. According to that I updated my if statements in the Ansible playbook and everything works as it should. 
Thank you for answers. Next time, when I create the question topic I would provide MCVE immediately.